# Is there a way to run an exe inside --onfile python

Tags: python, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

I created an main.py
Where the code is on.system('program.exe')
And I compiled it with auto-py-to-exe as one file added the program.exe as add files when I execute it says program.exe is not recognized as internal or external error lease help thank you

The problem is too complex for me please help

Comment: you can either provide and absolute path to the exe file or you can compile the exe with your program.   either way create an [mre]

Answer (score 0):

You are not supplying a ton of context but I am pretty sure this is because your compiled Python script cannot find `program.exe`. And this is probably because the "current working directory" is not the one containing `program.exe`. An easy solution would be to specify the complete path like `C:\path\to\program.exe`.

Comment: but i wanna run it secretely compiling it in a same file